# .toggle() on figcaption not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made my caption overlay my image and I wanted to add a display on hover functionality to it. But I can't get it to work

### CSS

```
figure 
{
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;

    figcaption 
    {
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: #ccc;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

### HTML

```
<figure>
    <a href = "#"><img src = "http://someimage.com/image.png"></a>                  
    <figcaption id="caption" style = "display: none">
        <p> Some caption text </p>
        <a href = '#'>link to author's bio</a>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

And finally my very simplistic javascript. I know the hover functionality is working correctly because my console has a "hello" when I enter the figure and a "goodbye" when I leave. There is no "complete" message.

### JQUERY

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

    $('figure').hover(function ()
    {
        console.log('hello');
        $('figcaption').toggle(slow,function(){ console.log("complete");} );
    },
    function ()
    {
        console.log('goodbye');
        $('figcaption').toggle(slow,function(){ console.log("complete");});
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put slow in quotation marks since it's a string and it will work:

```
$('figcaption').toggle("slow",function(){ console.log("complete");} );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ5n3/1/)

Comment: oh my goodness. It's funny that the problems that keep you banging your head against the wall are often so simple! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have an error in the console. Change `slow` to `"slow"`.

It's a string.

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) :

> duration (default: 400) Type: Number or String A string or number
>   determining how long the animation will run.

Answer (score 1):

Slow is a string:

```
$('figure').hover(
    function(){
        console.log('hello');
$('figcaption').toggle("slow",function(){ console.log("complete");} );
    },function(){
        console.log('goodbye');
$('figcaption').toggle("slow",function(){ console.log("complete");});
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RX5QA/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors on your page

[Check out the fiddle for a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8ZWN/2/)

1. `slow` should be `"slow"`
2. you did not close the image tag
3. you have one css class nested inside the other

For future reference. Browsers have JavaScript consoles that print debug information. You must know this as you are using console.log(). If your current browser does not print information like:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: slow is not defined`

I would recommend you tweak your console settings or install a thrird party one. There are many excellent choices out there